# Create a newsfeed page with real time data from users using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, signalr, real-time

I want to make a small web app using ASP .NET for intranet usage where users can send messages to either everyone or personal messages to a selected user from a drop down list.

The functions:
Send a broadcast message to everyone.
Send a personal message to a selective user.
Receive messages in real time.
Show who is online and their status.
Hear alert sound for new messages.

Is this all possible with ASP.NET? I thought I can easily make it with silver light but I don't have experience on that field.

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible. Take a look at Jabbr http://about.jabbr.net/. Made using ASP.NET and SignalR.